# clicking on dynamic values in a web table in selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

Below is my Table structure:

[image]

I want to click on the first cell of "policyno " column only if value is not empty

How do I achieve this?

Comment: can we have the DOM please?

Comment: you can check with the xpath `//a[starts-with(text(),"PHPK")]'.`driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[starts-with(text(),'PHPK')]")).click()`

Comment: hi murthi. it worked

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't specified, I have no idea what programming language do you need, but the idea is the same for all. I've used C# for the code below:

1. Get all the policy number elements. This can be easily achieved by getting the elements by xpath. In your case, I expect the `lblPolicyNumber` to be present in all:

   IList allPolicyElems = driver.FindElements(By.Xpath(".//*[contains(@id,'lblPolicyElements')]"));
2. Now, you have 2 options to click on the element you need. First, you click on an element using his position in the list: `allPolicyElems[0].Click();` (not the best way to do it) or by using LINQ (or lambda expressions for Java) to get the element by the text (perhaps you have the text stored in a variable from some previous actions): `allPolicyElems.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Text == "your_text_here").Click();`

This can be further expanded by applying the same logic in case you need to get the correct element by knowing other cell values from the same row.

Comment: i am using java and selenium

Answer (score 0):

**Try using this.**

```
WebElement elem = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table/tbody/tr[2]/td[3]/span/a"));

if(!(elem.getText().trim().equals(""))){
    elem.click();
}
```